# Conditions for a diagonal induced metric?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension $n$ with a (say Lorentzian) metric $g$, that is diagonal in some choice of local coordinates.

Let $S$ be manifold of dimension $k<n$ , embedded in $M$ by some injection $f: S
\rightarrow M$, some collection of local coordinates $C$ that cover it.

What are sufficient conditions on $f$ and $S$ and $C$, such that  the metric on $S$ induced by the pullback of $f$, $f^* g$, is diagonal everywhere with atlas $C$?

*Some motivation:*

Some canonical examples of embedding manifolds and computing induced metrics are embedding the sphere and the torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$. For both of these examples the induced metric happen to be diagonal. But then one is led to ask - do all surfaces embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ have diagonal induced metrics in their usual coordinates? If the answer is no, what's a sufficient condition?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/q/164960 (Note that the MO thread is about diagonalizing an arbitrary Einstein metric, and is unsolved. It may be that knowing the metric is induced from a diagonal one provides enough information to diagonalize it. Yet, this problem is *hard*, and in the generality as you stated it, there is no answer, though there are many individual results you can find by seraching.) For 3D Riemannian manifolds, the metric is always locally diagonal, regardless of whether it is induced or not, see also MO.

Comment: The first sentence is written as if the diagonal metric was a property of the manifold itself. It's not. It's a property of the local coordinate chart. Likewise the examples of the sphere and torus are written as if the diagonal metric was independent of the coordinates. It's not.

Comment: @BenCrowell Yes you're correct, let me modify my wording.

Comment: Another thing - in the Riemannian case, the Nash embedding theorem tells you that *all* metrics are actually induced from the diagonal Euclidean one, but it seems that there are non-diagonal Riemannian metrics, see e.g. [here](http://iopscience.iop.org/0264-9381/9/7/005/pdf/cq920705.pdf) where conditions for Riemannian diagonalizability are found.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Very interesting references thank you